# Where can I download .asc public key for Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-install, debian

From where I can download the .asc public key for Tor Browser?
I don't want to add the key using `gpg --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org`
because I read a [note on Github](https://gist.github.com/rjhansen/67ab921ffb4084c865b3618d6955275f) and that advises high-risk users to stop using the keyserver network immediately.

Where I can find .asc public key ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know who the person is that wrote that, but the official documentation searches the keyserver to get it.  See here: https://support.torproject.org/tbb/how-to-verify-signature/

On Linux you can run the GPG command through torsocks for a greater level of anonymity.

Answer (score 1):

The WKD URL for the validation key for TBB is

```
https://openpgpkey.torproject.org/.well-known/openpgpkey/hu/kounek7zrdx745qydx6p59t9mqjpuhdf
```

However, using the command given in the official instructions doesn't contact the public keyserver network, so you wouldn't be at risk of that attack anyway, even if you were a high risk user.